# Namespace with Context.Handler and Server.Transfer?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

What .NET namespace or class includes both Context.Handler and Server.Transfer?

I think one may include both and my hunt on MSDN returned null.

Answer (score 2):

System.Web.

```
HttpContext.Current.Handler
HttpContext.Current.Request.Server.Transfer
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hmmmm, I talking about them as they are implemented here:
>
> http://blog.benday.com/archive/2008/03/31/23176.aspx
>
> (at least Context.Handler there)
>
> I am still having trouble in VS making that reference.

Context.Handler is an instance of an HttpContext.

HttpContext exposes the CURRENT instance for the request under the HttpContext.Current property, however the current context can also be passed in HTTPHandlers in the ProcessRequest method:

```
void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```